# Unable to get utf8 characters from SQL server in ruby cucumber automation

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I'm using Ruby cucumber to automate my application. I'm using DSN ODBC driver and "dbi" to connect to my sql server 2012 DB. It is connected successfully and I can get the records. But when I'm trying to get unicode (utf-8) data from a table in ruby scripts, I get garbage characters (`???????`).

Please help me get unicode characters from DB.

Below is the code what I have used to connect and retrieve data from DB.

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'rubygems'
require 'DBI'
 def run_select_query_verifyText(query,verifyString)
    connection = nil
        status = false
      begin
          #puts "Connecting to DataBase"
                connection = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:ODBCDriver','test','xxxxx')
         rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
           puts "An error occurred"
           puts "Error code:    #{e.err}"
           puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
           return false
      end

        #execute sql query
        dataset = connection.execute(query)#.fetch_all
        dataset.each do |row|
            row.each do |data|
            puts "cell data is #{data}"

                if data == verifyString then

                    status = true
                    break
                end
            end
            if status then
                break
            end
        end
        connection.disconnect

       return status
    end
```

Comment: I remember Ruby 1.8 having trouble with unicode. Ruby 1.9 should be better. Which version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, which is fixed with following line in env.rb file

```
ENV['CUCUMBER_OUTPUT_ENCODING'] = 'UFT-8'
```